# Google Data Studio Dates and Text

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I am having trouble with two things trying to setup my report on Google Data Studio.

1. Using numbers with dates.

I have some numeric values to use with dates. However, I have the same date for different values and google sums up those values and I need them separated.

Also, when a certain day does not have any value, google gives it value 0 and I cant have that because the value isnt 0, I just need it to skip those days. I have generated a graph as an example.

2. I can´t generate a graph using text as a dimension. I think I am doing something wrong but I wasn´t able to.

**Table:**

[image: table]

**Graph:**

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

1) On the line chart, set the *date* as **dimension**, set the *city* as the **breakdown** **dimension**, the *clicks* as the **metric**.

2) create a chart filter and *exclude* when the "*clicks are null*"